# cuda gdb: the kernel indicated is not in the code

Tags: exception, pointers, cuda, cuda-gdb

My original problem, is that I have functions with a long list of arguments, that exceeded the memory that is allowed to be passed as an argument to a cuda kernel (I don't remember how many bytes, because it's been a while since I dealt with that). So, the way I bypassed this problem, was to define a new structure that its members are pointers pointing to other structures that I can dereference from within the kernel later.

... this is where the current problem begins: at the point where I'm trying to dereference the pointers (members of the structure I created earlier) from within the kernel, I get `CUDA_EXCEPTION_5, Warp Out-of-range Address`
...from the cuda-gdb. And of top of that, the kernel name and arguments (which are reported 'not live at this point' which cuda-gdb gives as the one with the error, is not one that I created in my code.

Now, for the more specifics :

here are the structures involved:

```
typedef struct {

    int strx;
    int stry;
    int strz;
    float* el;

} manmat;

typedef struct {

    manmat *x;
    manmat *y;
    manmat *z;

} manmatvec;
```

here's how i'm trying to group the kernel's arguments inside the main:

```
int main () {

...
...

    manmat resu0;
    resu0.strx = n+2;       resu0.stry = m+2;       resu0.strz = l+2;
    if (cudaMalloc((void**)&resu0.el,sizeof(float) * (n+2)*(m+2)*(l+2)) != cudaSuccess) cout << endl << " ERROR allocating memory for manmat resu0" << endl ;
    manmat resv0;
    resv0.strx = n+2;       resv0.stry = m+2;       resv0.strz = l+2;
    if (cudaMalloc((void**)&resv0.el,sizeof(float) * (n+2)*(m+2)*(l+2)) != cudaSuccess) cout << endl << " ERROR allocating memory for manmat resv0" << endl ;
    manmat resw0;
    resw0.strx = n+2;       resw0.stry = m+2;       resw0.strz = l+2;
    if (cudaMalloc((void**)&resw0.el,sizeof(float) * (n+2)*(m+2)*(l+2)) != cudaSuccess) cout << endl << " ERROR allocating memory for manmat resw0" << endl ;
    manmatvec residues0 ;

    residues0.x = &resu0;
    residues0.y = &resv0;
    residues0.z = &resw0;

    exec_res_std_2d <<<numBlocks2D, threadsPerBlock2D>>> (residues0, ......) ;

 .....
}
```

... and this is what happens in the kernel :

```
__global__ void exec_res_std_2d (manmatvec residues, ......) {

    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int k = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    manmat *resup;
    manmat *resvp;
    manmat *reswp;

    resup = residues.x;
    resvp = residues.y;
    reswp = residues.z;

    manmat resu, resv, resw ;

    resu.strx = (*resup).strx;     //LINE 1626
    resu.stry = (*resup).stry;
    resu.strz = (*resup).strz;
    resu.el = (*resup).el;

    resv = *resvp;
    resw = *reswp;

    .....
}
```

and finally, this is what cuda-gdb gives as output :

```
..................
[Launch of CUDA Kernel 1065 (exec_res_std_2d<<<(1,2,1),(32,16,1)>>>) on Device 0]
[Launch of CUDA Kernel 1066 (exec_res_bot_2d<<<(1,2,1),(32,16,1)>>>) on Device 0]

Program received signal CUDA_EXCEPTION_5, Warp Out-of-range Address.
[Switching focus to CUDA kernel 1065, grid 1066, block (0,0,0), thread (0,2,0), device 0, sm 0, warp 2, lane 0]
0x0000000003179020 in fdivide<<<(1,2,1),(32,16,1)>>> (a=warning: Variable is not live at this point. Value is undetermined.
..., pt=warning: Variable is not live at this point. Value is undetermined.
..., cells=warning: Variable is not live at this point. Value is undetermined.
...) at ola.cu:1626
1626    ola.cu: No such file or directory.
    in ola.cu
```

I have to note that I haven't defined ANY function , `__device__` or `__global__` in my code called `fdivide`.....

Also, it might be important to say that, in the beginning of the run of the program inside the debugger, despite the fact that I compile my cuda c files with `-arch=sm_20  -g -G -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20`, I get,

```
[New Thread 0x7ffff3b69700 (LWP 12465)]
[Context Create of context 0x1292340 on Device 0]
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /tmp/cuda-dbg/12456/session1/elf.1292340.1619c10.o.LkkWns
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /tmp/cuda-dbg/12456/session1/elf.1292340.1940ad0.o.aHtC7W
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /tmp/cuda-dbg/12456/session1/elf.1292340.2745680.o.bVXEWl
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /tmp/cuda-dbg/12456/session1/elf.1292340.2c438b0.o.cgUqiP
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /tmp/cuda-dbg/12456/session1/elf.1292340.2c43980.o.4diaQ4
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /tmp/cuda-dbg/12456/session1/elf.1292340.2dc9380.o.YYJAr5
```

Any answers or hints, or suggestions that could help me with this issue are very welcome!
please note that i've only recently started programming with cuda-c, and I'm not very experienced with cuda-gdb. Most of the debugging I did in C code I did it 'manually' by checking the output at various points of the code....

Also, this code is running on tesla M2090, and is also compiled to run on 2.0 architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a problem:

```
manmatvec residues0 ;

    residues0.x = &resu0;
    residues0.y = &resv0;
    residues0.z = &resw0;
```

The `resu0`, `resv0`, and `resw0` variables are allocated in host memory - on the host stack. You're putting host addresses into the manmatvec structure, then passing the manmatvec into the kernel.  On the receiving end, the CUDA code cannot access the host memory addresses provided in the structure.

If you're going to pass the addresses of the `resu0`, `resv0`, `resw0` variables, you need to allocate them from device memory.

I don't know if this is the entire problem, but I'm pretty sure it's a top contributor.

Comment: I understand your argument, and you are right that these are allocated on the host side. But the whole point of their existence is that I  use them to access and manipulate memory on the device side (the pointer member points to device memory)

So I guess my next question is how do I allocate them from the device side and have them on global memory so that they can be used by other kernels... ?

thank you again for your response

Comment: Not just allocated on the host side. The residue variables *reside* in host memory. The device can't access host memory. That's why you're getting an exception on line 1626 - where the device is attempting to dereference a pointer that contains a host memory address. You need to allocate the residue variables in device memory on the host side. This makes setting their values more difficult on the host side.

Comment: (1) calculate size of device memory 3 * (sizeof(manmat) + (sizeof(float) * ((n + 2) + (m + 3) + (l + 2))). NOTE: I don't know why you were doing '*' in this calculation.  (2) malloc a piece of host memory and cudaMalloc a piece of device memory. (3) cast host pointers to for each of the submemory allocations and fill in values. When setting manmat.el field use a deviceptr (not a host pointer). (4) cudaMemcpy from host to device. (5) fill in manmatvec with deviceptrs. If your size calculation was (n+m+l+6)*4 and the total sum is less than 4K then you can pass all of this by parameters.